# Criar array associativo para armazenar estrutura de dados

Tags: php, array-associativo

Minha dúvida se baseia em: "Eu tenho um pequeno trecho de código onde o usuário digita quantos colégios existem na região, quantas salas existem, quantas matérias e quantos alunos. Até aqui é tranquilo definir. O problema é a junção destes campos e conforme a quantidade de alunos for incluído um nome para eles. Ex descritivo:

- Qtd de alunos : 16;
- Qtd de Colegio : 2;
- Qtd de materia : 2;
- Qtd de sala   : 2;

Assim eu devo adicionar ao *array* (associativo) um nome para esses alunos e depois emitir uma pesquisa mostrando por exemplo quais são os alunos da sala 0 (tratando-se do *array*); Além disso não tenho certeza se deverá ser um associativo, pois estou guardando os outros campos em variáveis.

Código até agora:

```
function f_veri_conteudo()
{

    if(document.forms["cad_op"].tx_cole.value == ""){
        alert("Informe a quantidade de colegios!");
        return false;
    }
    else{

        w_cole = document.forms["cad_op"].tx_cole.value;

    }

    if(document.forms["cad_op"].tx_sala.value == ""){
        alert("Informe a quantidade de salas!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        w_sala = document.forms["cad_op"].tx_sala.value;
    }   

    if(document.forms["cad_op"].tx_mate.value == ""){
        alert("Informe a quantidade de materias!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        w_mate = document.forms["cad_op"].tx_mate.value;
    }

    if(document.forms["cad_op"].tx_alun.value == ""){
        alert("Informe a quantidade de alunos!");
        return false;
    }   

    var w_min_cole = parseInt(w_sala)+ parseInt(w_sala);
    w_min_cole = w_min_cole * w_cole;
    w_min_cole = w_min_cole * w_mate;

    if(document.forms["cad_op"].tx_alun.value < w_min_cole)
    {
        alert("informe no minimo "+w_min_cole+" alunos!");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        w_alun = document.forms["cad_op"].tx_alun.value;
    }

    alert("adicionado com sucesso!");
  }
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="cad_op">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="arial" size="-1">Colegio:</font>
            <input type="text" id="id_cole" name="tx_cole" size="5" maxlength="3" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="arial" size="-1">Salas:</font>
            <input type="text" id="id_sala" name="tx_sala" size="5" maxlength="3" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="arial" size="-1">Materia:</font>
            <input type="text" id="id_mate" name="tx_mate" size="5" maxlength="3" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="arial" size="-1">Alunos:</font>
            <input type="text" id="id_alun" name="tx_alun" size="5" maxlength="3" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button type="button" name="btn_mate" style="width:55" onclick="f_veri_conteudo();">Enviar</button>         
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Assim como um exemplo eu teria o array:

```
$array_pessoa['S'] = $array_sala;
$array_pessoa['C'] = $array_cole;
$array_pessoa['M'] = $array_mate;
```

E queria informar como um exemplo na posição **0** de cada um dos índices do `$array_pessoa` um nome e assim consecutivamente. Ai depois mostrar qual pessoa está na matéria tal ou sala tal (conforme a posição).

Comment: Já fez alguma coisa? Tente e poste aqui.

Comment: @bigown como pode ver só fiz o "corpo" do programa, não consigo ir em frente por causa de adicionar um aluno para cada coisa!